# Sum column where date column equals year - SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

Not sure how to title this Q. Basically i would like to add a column AvailableHoursForYear which sums the AvailableHours by BookedMonth year.

```
BookedMonth           AvailableHours
2014-10-01 00:00:00   120
2015-01-01 00:00:00   90
2015-02-01 00:00:00   150
```

Assuming this is my only data, i want the table to read

```
 BookedMonth              AvailableHours     AvailableHoursForYear
2014-10-01 00:00:00       120                120
2015-01-01 00:00:00       90                 240
2015-02-01 00:00:00       150                240
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`SUM OVER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT BookedMonth, AvailableHours,
       SUM(AvailableHours) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(BookedMonth)) AS AvailableHoursForYear
FROM mytable
```

The `SUM`, when used with the `OVER` clause, is applied over a window of records as defined by the arguments of `OVER`: in this case `SUM` returns the sum of `AvailableHours` per year of `BookedMonth`.

Comment: @LeeS Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Can you add a 2nd condition? Lets say i had another column called TYPE. And i wanted AvailableHoursForYear when TYPE = 1

Comment: @LeeS Sure, you can use: `SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN AvailableHours END) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(BookedMonth))`